# Trying to add html5shiv.js to my code so it can render with IE

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="Description" content="C.V"/>
```

I have added code below to render in IE but will not work.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="Assets/html5shiv/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="Assets/aboutme.css"/>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen exactly?

Comment: Are you actually using a version of Internet Explorer older than version 9 to test this code?

Comment: Thanks guys!. I am using the latest version of IE and none of my CSS styles are rendering. So I added the javaScript and still no joy

Comment: What is the issue here? Do you have any error ?

Comment: @Adrien Hi and thanks, I am not getting any error just that my page is rendering without css styles. Pages render ok in other browsers but will not in IE. have tried the html5shiv but still IE will not render CSS styles.

Comment: @JhoseIIRod thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to target all versions of IE(except 10) use this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

For IE 10 check this:
[IE 10 Specific Styles](https://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/)

hope it helps.

EDIT:
and last, check this for IE 11 & 12+(EDGE) [Detect Internet Explorer (IE) up to version 11 and Edge (12+)](https://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/vEJNZN?editors=0010)